# Active Directory computer name is different than computer name on PC

Tags: active-directory, domain

I have a computer that I have imaged and named EX-DKTP-EX-01. Yet, when I get on my Active directory for my domain the computer name is still the old computer name (EXMMIST) that came with the computer. Can anyone explain why this is happening? Let me know if I need to provide more information. This computer is on the domain.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you get the object properties with PowerShell and post back? Get-AdComputer $computername | FL *

Comment: DistinguishedName  : CN=MXL421,OU= Staff Desktops,OU= Staff Computers,OU= Computers,DC=company,DC=org
DNSHostName        : MXL421.company.org
Enabled            : True
Name               : MXL421
ObjectClass        : computer
ObjectGUID         : ecf752b0-d149-48a6-88a9-a3567069de72
SamAccountName     : MXL421$
SID                : S-1-5-21-73586283-1364589140-725345543-16263
UserPrincipalName  :
PropertyNames      : {DistinguishedName, DNSHostName, Enabled, Name...}
AddedProperties    : {}
RemovedProperties  : {}
ModifiedProperties : {}
PropertyCount      : 9

Comment: Any insights on this?

Comment: Huh? Is MXL421 the same computer?!

Comment: Yes, it is the computer, it's why I listed its distinct properties. I was just using a computer name I made up above to at least try and be a bit discreet obviously.